# Multiple relative urls and sites in Nginx

Tags: php, python, django, wordpress, nginx

I have a server with a name of compute01.com

I have a python django application through a reverse proxy, a gitlab instance, a mediawiki php instance, and a wordpress php instance on this server.

my goal is to have the urls set up as:

```
compute01.com/django/
compute01.com/gitlab/
compute01.com/wiki/
compute01.com/wordpress/
```

so far I only have gitlab running with its own sites-enabled file

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   listen compute01.com:80 default_server;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   ##listen [::]:80 default_server;                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   server_name compute01.com;                                                                                                                                       
   server_tokens off;                                                                                                                                                     
   root /home/git/gitlab/public;                                                                                                                                                                                                                

   client_max_body_size 20m;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;                                                                                                                                                                                                
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;                                                                                                                                                                                                 

   location /gitlab {                                                                                                                                                                      
     try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }

   location /django {                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                                                                                              
    }
```

I added the django location added to this file because its the only I way I can add that relative url to talk to the wsgi. however 404s and such get redirected to gitlab.

What I would like is four separate files in sites enabled that have the individual urls and location blocks however I am not sure what the structure would be, would it be " 4 servers" or "4 locations at a server"?

Comment: I would try a separate subdomain and server block for each site in separate files.